# kineticjs tween on android left the original image

Tags: kineticjs, tween, browser-bugs

I'm using KineticJs to develop a webapp, but i found that when i'm using tween() on android, it always left a original image when the tween starts. And it's also happens on the Kineticjs tutorials page with my galaxy note2.  is it a bug?

here is my screen shot...
[image: http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/53e19610gw1eakknhy9jkj216h1kwncx.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This is an android canvas bug.

One of tips - draw on canvas after small delay:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage(conf);
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

stage.add(layer);

setTimeout(function(){
    // add shapes to the layer and then do layer.draw()
}, 300);
```

See full list of tips there: http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/